# Slow Deployment

Tags: android, performance, deployment

My current game project is getting large enough that when I deploy for testing I'm waiting a few minutes to actually get this to my phone. Sometimes I have other things to work on, but sometimes I have to sit and wait. This is unfortunately slowing down the development process.

I'm already sure the biggest factor in this is package size. My package is now just under 18 Megs, but I know there are apps out there with much larger packages.

Is there any tricks, phone settings, or eclipse settings that might speed deployment other than reducing the package size?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this doesn't quite meet your criteria of 'other than reducing the package size', my guess is that most of that filesize probably comes from textures and audio resources.

Instead of packing them all in the APK under the `res/` folder, I might recommend temporarily copying the resources to the device's filesystem, and then load them from there instead of your resources. Then when you repeatedly upload your APK you don't have to keep transferring the same resources over and over.

If you load your resources from a mostly centralized location it should be just a couple lines of code change to change from loading from res to loading from a file. You can repackage them as resources again when your game is closer to release and you don't have to do so many iterations.

Comment: That actually is a good idea... I will consider this. I know on the app market there is an option for expansion APKs... I don't know much about them. Is it possible to actually have the assets in a separate APK and referencing them in the game code? This could offer a massive advantage of having different expansions or modes (ie fantasy and sci fi) assets in different APKs.

Comment: That may be possible, though I have never explored the use of expansion APKs. This also crossed my mind when I was writing my answer, but I didn't know enough about their functionality to comment on them. @user1704841

Comment: I'm actually accepting this answer because looking into multiple APKs I have learned it is possible to use one APK for assets and one APK for code updates. This will shorten deployment greatly for me when updating my game engine instead of my game assets and vice versa. Also, I found out I cannot have multiple versions of assets. I would have to upload them as separate apps.

Answer (score 1):

what you want is an android emulator. you can install the emulator as a Eclipse IDE plugin.

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

@"Unfortunately my system is so slow (and old) that the emulator runs like molasses in comparison to running the app on the actual device."
http://dev.blogs.nuxeo.com/2011/10/speeding-up-the-android-emulator.html

Comment: I think this is the first time I've ever seen the emulator suggested in order to increase speed...

Comment: that or he can continue to scp the package to his external device. i think in terms of conveince and speed this option is a best bet.

Comment: Yup, I agree. It's just that usually people complain about the emulator being slow. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately my system is so slow (and old) that the emulator runs like molasses in comparison to running the app on the actual device.

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium 64; 4GB RAM; AMD C-50 (2 CPUs) ~1Ghz. I am aware this is dismal for development and a new unit would increase performance. Unfortunately that doesn't fit into my budget at the moment.

Comment: @user1704841 try running android through virtual box using the guide above. you will be able to devote many more system resources than the emulator as a plugin allows.

Comment: I'll look into this momentarily

Comment: I notice that the download page mentions specific computers. I am running a Toshiba Satellite which they do not have a version for. I was trying to find info on if using a different one is potentionally damaging to the hardware, but I didn't see any info on it. Do you know if it poses a risk?

Comment: @user1704841 the main thing you want to check for is if your computer allows virtualization. you can check for this info in your BIOS at startup.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I am choosing to use two APKs instead. It seems that the two APKs seems like less work to set up on my end, and since I am planning to have different artwork versions of my game separating the artwork and code into two APKs makes more sense for my situation.